# Making a border from a grouped graphic

Tags: pathfinder, illustrator-effects

I have a vector version of the Maryland flag (lots of shapes grouped into one rectangle). I want to cut a rectangle out of the centre, to use the flag as a border. I draw a rectangle inside the flag and with both selected, choose minus front from pathfinder but that takes everything away except the bottom right corner. Don't understand why. Do I need to do something else with the grouped objects that make up the flag. Tried to make a compound path but that turned everything yellow (one of the colours in the flag.)

Having difficulty all around with this flag, including making clipping masks to put flag inside shapes. Is there some trick to using a grouped image to make clipping masks or other paths?

Comment: Can you place the flag beneath whatever goes on top? So your top artwork extends almost to the edge, revealing only the desired border?

Comment: Or can you work in InDesign or Photoshop? Place the vector flag, and give it a layer mask.

Answer (score 1):

Select all the objects that make up the flag and group them. Draw a new rectangle over your group. Make one selection of rect. and group, rightclick and create clipping mask. Select new masked object, go to brushes and select create new brush, select make pattern brush. Play around with pattern brush dialogue to achieve results you want.